# How to set image at runtime in crystalreports ole object bitmap image from local path in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

The Page_Load function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        }
```